# Node.js >= 0.12.* C++ Addon instantiation returning a callback

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I have the following functionality working with no issues so long that the call back parameters are string:

```
void Server::AppUse(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {

    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();

    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    Local<Function> nextCb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);

    Local<Function> argv[2] = {
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello world"),
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello again"), 
    };

    nextCb->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 2, argv);

}
```

Implementation in node:

```
var app = require('./build/Release/middleware');

app.use(function (next, again) {
       console.log(next);
       console.log(again);;
});
```

This outputs the following implementing node:

```
$ node ./example.js
hello world
hello again
```

However, now I want to add a call back. for example:

```
void Server::AppUse(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {

    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();

    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    Local<Function> nextCb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);

    Local<Function> argv[1] = {
        nextCb 
    };

    nextCb->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 1, argv);

}
```

This results in a C++ compilation error:

```
./src/server.cc:73:63: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Function::Call(v8::Local<v8::Object>, int, v8::Local<v8::Function> [1])’
../src/server.cc:73:63: note: candidate is:
In file included from ~/.node-gyp/0.12.4/src/node.h:61:0,
                 from ../src/server.cc:1:
~/.node-gyp/0.12.4/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2557:16: note: v8::Local<v8::Value> v8::Function::Call(v8::Handle<v8::Value>, int, v8::Handle<v8::Value>*)
```

This basically means that V8::Call only expects an array of values. But what If I wanted to return Function? There is no example in the current addon documentation.

Answer (score 1):

### Functions are Values

Casting back and forth really doesn't change the underlying object, rather exposes different member functions.  In your case, declare instead

```
Local<Value> argv[1] = {
    nextCb 
};
```

### Some v8 class Hierarchy info

Yes, **argv** is an array of *Value*, however, almost everything (including *Function*) is - as the following *v8* class diagram illustrates; this is taken from [thlorenz.com](http://thlorenz.com/v8-dox/build/v8-3.25.30/html/dc/d0a/classv8_1_1_value.html), one of the many v8 documentation sites.

[image]

Requiring a *Value* is nearly the least opinionated a declaration can be since it assumes the least, a *Function* is an *Object* and *Object* is a *Value*, thus a *Function* can appear anywhere that expects a *Value*, going the opposite direction is also allowed using Cast, but the underlying object has to be the actual thing.

### Example

For example, the following is legal

```
void someFunction(const Local<Function> &cb)
{
    Local<Value> v = cb;
    Local<Function> andBack = Local<Function>::Cast(v);
}
```